# Terraform error: Could not contact any CDS load balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I've set up my ec2 instance of AWS using Terraform.  I ssh into the instance & try to install Apache via Yum. I run this code (as the root user):

```
sudo yum install -y httpd
```

and I get the error:

```
Could not contact any CDS load balancers: rhui2-cds01.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com, rhui2-cds02.us-east-1.aws.ce.redhat.com.
```

This Linux Redhat

Here is the Networking Config

```
resource "aws_default_subnet" "learntf_default_subnet" { 
 availability_zone = "us-east-1a" 
} 

resource "aws_security_group" "web_server_sec_group" { 
    name = "web server security group" 
    # allow ssh only 
    ingress { 
        from_port = 0
        to_port = 22 
        protocol = "tcp" 
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
    } 

    ingress { 
        from_port = 0 
        to_port = 80 
        protocol = "tcp" 
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
    } 

    egress { 
        from_port = 0 
        to_port = 0 
        protocol = "-1" 
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
    } 
}
```

I'm using the default VPC security

Comment: There are a lot of details missing. Which Linux distro, how is the networking configured, are there any security groups or NACLs?

Comment: Does this help: https://serverfault.com/questions/752818/yum-could-not-contact-cds-load-balancer-in-aws?